# Hide first 4 div after every 10th div element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to hide after every 10 div element first 4 div element. So how it's possible using `nth-of-type` OR any other style css.

Any one have idea for my question then please update me.

Comment: Provide your code

Comment: what you mean by this? "after every 10 div element first 4 div element."

Comment: Means i have displayed latest posts list. After every first 10 post list i want to hide next 4 post (means 11th, 12th, 13th and 14th) and same this process continue for next 21th, 22th, 23th and 24th post. So how can i hide this 4 post using style.css ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use `nth-child` css selector here...you want 4 elements after every 10th element so use `10n+11`, `10n+12`, `10n+13`, `10n+14`...

***Note***: I have changed the color of selected element just for visual...use `display:none` to hide...

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.parent div:nth-child(10n+11),
.parent div:nth-child(10n+12),
.parent div:nth-child(10n+13),
.parent div:nth-child(10n+14) {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}

.parent div {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
  font: 13px Verdana;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 4px;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>
  <div>13</div>
  <div>14</div>
  <div>15</div>
  <div>16</div>
  <div>17</div>
  <div>18</div>
  <div>19</div>
  <div>20</div>
  <div>21</div>
  <div>22</div>
  <div>23</div>
  <div>24</div>
  <div>25</div>
  <div>26</div>
</div>
```